# Abbreviare "circa" con "ca." è considerata una prassi scorretta?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Mi è stato contestato in un powerpoint l'utilizzo dell'abbreviazione ca. al posto di "circa" per indicare un'incertezza nella misura di un parametro. Volevo capire se effettivamente abbreviare "circa" con  "ca." viene considerato un errore o sconsigliato.

Comment: È “incorretto” che è scorretto! Scusa la battuta, ma “[incorretto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/incorretto/)” significa quasi solo “che non è stato corretto”, detto di bozze e simili.

Comment: Sei sicuro che la critica riguardasse proprio l'abbreviazione “ca.” e non qualche aspetto dell'approssimazione del parametro (magari si chiedeva un'indicazione esplicita del margine d'errore o altro)?

Comment: @DaG grazie, effettivamente sono sicuro che ca. venga utilizzato da molti e che sia in uso ma che non venga corretto quindi non credo sia scorretto dire che è un errore incorretto! :-)

Comment: @DaG mi hanno detto esplicitamente che era l'abbreviazione.

Comment: Abbreviare "circa" con "ca." è [sicuramente corretto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circa). Si può abbreviare anche con "c." e "ca". [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/circa/) suggerisce di abbreviare con "c.", ma spesso negli articoli della Treccani si trova l'abbreviazione ["ca."](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=b-iQU7HAGaqN8QeIn4GgDw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22ca%22+%22circa%22+treccani).

Comment: Non sono del tutto d'accordo che Treccani suggerisca di utilizzare "c." come abbreviazione di "circa". Tu hai guardato, giustamente, il vocabolario e la definizione di "circa". Ma, in quell'articolo, dato che si tratta di un lemma, "circa" viene abbreviato in "c." per seguire l'uso per cui tutti i lemmi, quando se ne dà una definizione, non vengono ripetuti per esteso, ma solo con l'iniziale. Se guardi, per esempio, il lemma "albero" o "automobile", troverai, all'interno dell'articolo, i due vocaboli abbreviati con "a." Il che non significa che "albero" o "automobile" siano tout-court da abbre

Comment: Nota che la Treccani dice [testualmente](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/circa/): «in altri casi, si abbrevia c. (nato c. 1320)».

Comment: Probabilmente _ca._ come abbreviazione è più frequente in inglese che in italiano. Forse chi l'ha vista ha pensato che fosse un "anglismo latino" (tipo _etc._ al posto di _ecc._)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

“Ca.” è sicuramente corretta. Se può servire una pezza d'appoggio, nel *Nuovo manuale di stile* di Roberto Lesina (Zanichelli), a pag. 191 viene data proprio come esempio di quel tipo di abbreviazioni costituite «da una contrazione che conserva lettere iniziali e lettere intermedie o finali del termine, sempre seguit[e] dal punto».